# Are RFC 2104 and FIPS 198 compatible with each other?

Tags: hmac, fips

Is the [FIPS 198 specification](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips198/fips-198a.pdf) of HMAC compatible with the [RFC specification for HMAC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2104)?

Answer (score 1):

When testing with two libraries, one implemented against the RFC and another implemented against the FIPS spec, both seem to produce the same results.